# Attempting to generate Pascal's Triangle as a tuple using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples, pascals-triangle

I need to write a function to generate Pascal's Triangle as a tuple using recursion.

```
e.g pascal(5)   
((1,), (1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 3, 1), (1, 4, 6, 4, 1))
```

I can generate it as a list with the following function:

```
def triangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    elif n == 1:
        return [[1]]
    else:
        new_row = [1]
        result = triangle(n-1)
        last_row = result[-1]
        for i in range(len(last_row)-1):
            new_row.append(last_row[i] + last_row[i+1])
        new_row += [1]
        result.append(new_row)
    return result
```

And I've tried changing this to a tuple:

```
def pascal(n):
    if n==0:
        return ()
    elif n==1:
        return ((1,),)
    else:
        new_row = (1,)
        result = pascal(n-1)
        last_row = result[-1]
        print(last_row)
        for i in range(len(last_row)-1):
            new_row = new_row+last_row[i]+last_row[i+1]
        new_row = new_row +(1,)
        result=result+(new_row,)
    return result
```

but it doesn't work and I get the error `len(last_row)-1 type int has no len`.

I'm not sure how to fix this code and would appreciate any help.

Comment: When you `print`  the `last_row` what are you seeing in the output? Because it's not a tuple...(hint hint)

Comment: @JaredSmith, yup i realised that, not sure how to fix the code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `result = result + new_row` line.

If you want to see why, mouseover below...

> `result` is a tuple of tuples, `new_row` is a tuple of numbers. If you add a tuple of numbers to a tuple of tuples, you end with a tuple of tuples *and* numbers! Such as `((1,), 1)` which is not what you want.
>
>  fix it by doing `result = result + (new_row,)`

Comment: After fixing this, i get a new error
line : new_row = new_row + last_row[i] + last_row[i+1]
can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

however if i change it to:
new_row = new_row+(last_row[i],)+(last_row[i+1],)
the output is totally different

Comment: That's a different problem :-). You should be able to work it out. `new_row` is a tuple of ints, last_row is a tuple of ints, so what is that line trying to do..? The error message is pretty helpful!

Comment: OK, so what does `(last_row[i],)+(last_row[i+1],)` give you? What do you want it to give you?

Comment: `last_row[i]` is the first element, and `last_row[i+1]` is the second, i.e. both numbers, yes, but `(last_row[i],)` is a tuple containing a number, so `(last_row[i],) + (last_row[i+1],)` is a tuple plus a tuple, which gives you another tuple (such as `(1,) + (2,) = (1, 2)`, but you want the sum of the last 2 elements, right..?

Comment: I figured it out :) thanks for your patience and guidance !

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, simply add this line before the `return` in order to convert the `list of lists` to `tuple of tuples`:

```
tuple_results = tuple(tuple(x) for x in results)
return tuple_results
```

Comment: This will only work if i add an inner function / use another function to do this, because this function is a recursive one. I would like to do it in one function. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: no, it will work like that if you have the same indentation for both lines (like I wrote).

Comment: result.append(new_row)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0):

### NOTE

Don't turn this in for homework. Your teacher will (correctly) gather that you cribbed it from the net. Primarily for learning purposes in terms of how compact this can be, i.e. how a professional Python programmer might write this.

So here it is, the short 8 line version:

```
def pascal(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ()
    elif n == 1:
        return ((1,),)
    else:
        res = pascal(n - 1) # recursive call
        return (*res, (1, *[n + i for n, i in zip(res[-1], res[-1][1:])], 1))    
print(pascal(5))
```

In this case, the part that was missing from your code is the spread operator. What it does is unpack that tuple of tuples from the recursive call to which you tack on the next row.

This is pretty dense, so lets unpack it a little:

```
return (*res, # open paren starts new tuple, *res unpacks the recursive call
    (1, # starts the tuple for the current row
      *[ # spread the result of the list comprehension
          n + i for n, i in # we're going to add the items in two lists
          zip( # here's where we combine the two lists to add
              res[-1], # last row of recursive call
              res[-1][1:] # same but shifted 1 index
          ),
       ], # end list comprehension
     1) # 1 to end the current row
  ) # end the total result, i.e. tuple of rows
```

This works because of how `zip` deals with lists of different lengths. For example, if the last row was `(1,3,3,1)` then we'd get `zip((1,3,3,1),(3,3,1))` which would be `((1,3), (3,3), (3,1))`. Then we add the digits in the pairs in the comprehension and get `(4,6,4)`. Tack on the ones and there's the next row.