# Make a following row of the pascal's triangle from the previous using reduce?

Tags: list, math, lambda, functional-programming

```
       [1]
     [1, 1]
    [1, 2, 1]
   [1, 3, 3, 1]
```

How to transform a list (row) into the subsequent one without loop - just using list.reduce(...) in Js, Kotlin, Scala, Swift or Java 8 Streams or whatever?

Comment: reduce generally returns a scalar. Applies function to first two elements, applies function to result and next element, keeps going until a scalar is returned. Why not use a loop?

Comment: Here's a recursive solution in python https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907685/3757232

Comment: @DanSp. just for the sake of it, I train myself to think without loops. So, no particular reason for doing it, it's just an exercise.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks, that's very impressive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this looks a lot like a discussion based on definitions. In many languages `reduce` only means function of following signature (some types imaginary syntax)

```
(coll: Collection[T], operation: (value:T, accumulator:T) => T) => T
```

In other words `reduce` only reduces elements of the collection into result of the same type. Under such definition you obviously can't get a new array from an array of integers. However in both [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Java 8 Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)  there is actually a `reduce` version which is closer to what other people might call `fold` (which is what it is called for example in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html)) with a more advanced signature such as

```
(coll: Collection[T], initialValue : U, operation: (value:T, accumulator:U) => U) => U
```

Using such `reduce` you can build the next row in the Pascal's triangle. For example using JavaScript:

```
const buildNext = arr => arr.reduce((acc,val) => {
        acc[acc.length - 1] += val;
        acc.push(val); 
        return acc;
    }, 
    [0]); // initial accumulator

console.log(buildNext[1,3,3,1]);
```

Note that in Java 8 Streams version the code will be more complicated because Streams were designed with parallel computation in mind so you have to provide one more function to join 2 `accumulator`s of different segments.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I was hoping for, thanks!

Comment: @cuddlecheek, you are welcome! Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: everything clear, I posted my kotlin approach based on your solution. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Sergr's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455585/3719696) rewritten to kotlin with immutable lists:

```
fun nthRowOfPascalTriangleRecursively(n: Long): List<Long> = when (n) {
    0L -> listOf(1)
    else -> nthRowOfPascalTriangleRecursively(n - 1)
            .fold(listOf(0L)) { acc, it -> acc.dropLast(1) + (acc.last() + it) + listOf(it) }
}
```